# How to Exclude Magento Review tab from tabs and show at bottom

Tags: product, store-view, review

hello guys can you help me in changing **Magento** review tab position , i want reviews to show after tabs to for more user friendly

Comment: Which your Magento version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you have using **Magento 1.X version**.

Just goto `local.xml or review.xml` of your theme a`pp/design/frontend/[Your_package]/[Your_package]/layout/`

Find the handler for  product page ***`catalog_product_view`*** then remove code:

```
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml" after="additional">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Reviews</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

**Then add below code:**

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml" >
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

then at view.phtml call this block by below code

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('reviews') ?>
```

Comment: bro one more question , now add new review section is not showing under all reviews, how i can do it

Comment: okay thanks i did it , it was path issue ..thanks

Comment: @AmitBera  Sir..how can u do same in M2. I did with few methods but it blank the home page. One example is below:

<referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="new_space"  htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container"  after="-">  
             <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="reviewform" as="review_form"   template="form.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_additional_data" template="product/view/list.phtml" />
            </container>  
</referenceContainer>

Comment: @AmitBera ..Above code display result what i want but home page go blank and error log display below error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in /site-root/html/vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Product/View.php:131

Stack trace:
#0 /siteRoot/html/vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Product/View/ListView.php(57): Magento\Review\Block\Product\View->getReviewsCollection()
#1 /siteRoot/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(658): Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView->_beforeToHtml()  ......

Please guide whats wrong. thx

Comment: will check at night. And get back to you at night

Comment: thx ..i will wait :)

Comment: @AmitBera  ..Sir..if you say ...i post a new question for this?

Comment: @AmitBera ..Sir..i posted a new question here and, if possible, have look at it. http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/151609/29175 . thank you