# Product page Review Section from tabs to Bottom of page

Tags: magento2, layout, review, product-page

I need to move/rearrange Reviews from tabs of product page to bottom of page. Here is how I updated my theme file's default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />    <!-- Removed tab  -->

        <referenceContainer name="content">
        <container name="new_space"  htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container"  after="-">  <!-- New Container to display at bottom of page -->
```

***This code works well*** and placed reviews at bottom of page but Home page of site goes blank and error log display below errors:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in /chroot/home/londonwa/londonwala.in/html/vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Product/View.php:131

My issue same issue like: [How to Exclude Magento Review tab from tabs and show at bottom](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/143241/29175)    but thats in magento 1.x version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento2, have *layout tag* ***`<move>`*** by which you ***move a block reference area to another area.***

Please add this code at **catalog_product_view.xml**  ***app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[ThemeName]/Magento_Catalog/layout***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- add this code -->
         <move element="reviews.tab" destination="content" after="-"/>
    <!-- end -->
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks. You all code worked well even which before 1st edit and i displayed it in content because its location where i needed. You are inspiration for me always. I can understand how you added and updated all code. Great Sir :)

Comment: you welcome @Jai.

Comment: @AmitBera - I am trying to do same but not displaying my review information in bottom page. Can you please help me?

Comment: If you're confused what is destination than here is the guide for it, you can refer to this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_mv
and it is placed in vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: @Amit Bera, I'm trying to move the review tab but it's not working. Please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281376/how-to-move-review-section-in-product-page and help me