# Magento 2.3 - Always show reviews on pageload

Tags: knockoutjs, magento2.3.3, product-review

I use the tab-view on the product page for mobile devices, but I show all the tabs open at once on the desktop view.

This causes a problem with the reviews. The form for adding a review is shown, but the existing reviews themselves don't show.

I realise they must be getting loaded by Knockout when normally you click the tab. But me having all the tabs open `onload` means the reviews never get shown. It does work however, if I add `#reviews` to the product.

`review.phtml` is loaded, but the JS in there doesn't seem to fire, I think this is the cause of this issue. Anyone got a lead on how to modify this so it does fire on page load?

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Review/js/process-reviews": {
            "productReviewUrl": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getProductReviewUrl())) ?>",
            "reviewsTabSelector": "#tab-label-reviews"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: same problem here. Any solution?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186255/magento-2-how-to-move-product-page-review-section-from-tabs-to-bottom-of-page#answer-212711