# Magento2.4.2 Show review form and list on different location on product page

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I'm showing the review tab on different locations using the following code, form is showing but the review list is not showing.

```
<?php
$layout = $block->getLayout();
?>
<div class="product_review"> 
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12" id="preview">
          <?= /* @noEscape */ $layout->renderElement('reviews.tab') ?>
      </div>   
</div>
```

I [tried](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/212711/21339)  to adjust the JS but it's not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since review list is updating via Ajax therefore I have maked as follow:

```
<div class="product_review"> 
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12" id="previewlist"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
          <?= /* @noEscape */ $layout->renderElement('reviews.tab') ?>
      </div>   

</div>
```

`process-reviews.js` JS changes as follow:

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * @param {String} url
     * @param {*} fromPages
     */
    function processReviews(url, fromPages) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'html',
            showLoader: false,
            loaderContext: $('.product.data.items')
        }).done(function (data) {            
            $('#previewlist').html(data).trigger('contentUpdated');
            $('[data-role="product-review"] .pages a').each(function (index, element) {
                $(element).click(function (event) { //eslint-disable-line max-nested-callbacks
                    processReviews($(element).attr('href'), true);
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        }).complete(function () {
            if (fromPages == true) { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#reviews').offset().top - 50
                }, 300);
            }
        });
    }

    return function (config) {
        processReviews(config.productReviewUrl);
        $(function () {
            $('.product-info-main .reviews-actions a').click(function (event) {
                var anchor, addReviewBlock;

                event.preventDefault();
                anchor = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*?(#|$)/, '');
                addReviewBlock = $('#previewlist');
                $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: addReviewBlock.offset().top - 50
                }, 300);

            });
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
<?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product,"sort",true); ?>
```

let me know if you need any more help

Comment: It's not working