# How to move Review section in product page?

Tags: review, product-page, magento2.3.2

We would like to move the review to the right side in product page as below.

On the picture below where there is a red X that is where the product description text can be and where there is a red O that is where we need to move the review section

[image]

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried move tag in layout xml?

Comment: Yes, but its not working

Comment: Use bootstrap, and create two column with bootstrap, add something in left column and put review in right column.

Comment: From the look of snapshot, After image div container work on full column, that's why your review box appearing on left

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I will try as per your suggestion.

Comment: Very hard to answer without knowing what customisations you have already made.

Comment: @Ben Crook, We have extended the luma theme and also we are in starting stage of website. We need to move the review section to the right side as mentioned in the screenshot.