# How to add back to top button in Magento 2?

Tags: phtml, magento2.3.2, infinte-scroll

I want to add **back to top** button on our site. I referred the below link http://magentosource.blogspot.com/2013/10/add-back-to-top-button-in-magento.html

But we have no footer.phtml.

Could anyone please help me where to add this footer.html and how to create back to top button?

Comment: You can try free extension for it. Use this url : https://www.solwininfotech.com/product/magento-2-extensions/scroll-to-top-magento-2/

Comment: @ChiragParmar, our requirement is to create the button without using extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your theme doesn't have `footer.phtml` then it is probably calling core `footer.phtml` which is:

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/footer.phtml
```

copy above `footer.phtml` to your theme directory `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/templates/html/` and do the needful there.

After your development in `footer.phtml` run these commands:

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

## Edit:

I have checked the link you have shared, it is not working. Please try this code below, you can add this code in `app/code/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/templates/html/header.phtml`

```
<div id="back_top" style="display: block;"></div>
<style type="text/css">
    #back_top {
    background-color: red;
    bottom: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    height: 44px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 200px;
    width: 54px;
    z-index:999;
}
</style>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function($){
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
                jQuery('#back_top').fadeIn();
            } else {
                jQuery('#back_top').fadeOut();
            }
        });
        jQuery("#back_top").click(function() {
            jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have copied "footer.phtml" and pasted into our theme directory but its not working.

Comment: @Siva check updated answer

Comment: @Thanks, Do i need to add anything regarding this footer.phtml in layout.xml file?

Comment: No nothing in `layout.xml` after deployment script check your website source on browser and verify if new code appearing

Comment: I have run the commands but still its not working. Could you please suggest how to add "back to top" button in Magento 2?

Comment: try same code in header.phtml file

Comment: Answer updated, please check

Comment: Checked and see that the header.phtml file also not available in our theme. Can i create header.phtml and put the above code? 
Please confirm the path: app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_theme/templates/html

Comment: no, don't create header.phtml, it will override your default header file. Please check header.phtml in your parent theme, you can check parent theme from your `theme.xml` file

Comment: If you find header.phtml file in parent theme, then copy that file into your theme directory and add script there

Comment: Sure, please confirm the path app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_theme/templates/html

Comment: Yes, this is the one. it depends on your theme. vendor/theme is example path

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working great!!

Comment: Can you please look into this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281376/how-to-move-review-section-in-product-page and help me?

Comment: Sure, let me try